# Getting error "something went wrong. to try again, reload the page and start the workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow

hello I have tried all the following below

1. restart service - Workflow Manager Backend
2. restart service - Service Bus Message Broker
3. restart service - Service Bus Gateway
4. restart service - Windows Fabric Host Service
5. recycle Workflow Manager application pool
6. restart WorkflowServiceBackend Service (using cmdlet or manuel)
7. cleared the sharepoint configration cache and restart SP timer service
8. reboot server
9. re-publish SP2013 workflow.
10. iis reset
11. flush the DNS cache : cmd "IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS"
12. Confirm User Profile Service from Central Administration and validated that user synchronizations were still occurring
    But I am still reviewing the error and it wont let me run any workflows ANY HELP would be very much appreciated I have been trying different things for two days now.

Comment: You need to check your ULS log to find the exact error cause workflow stop running. Also you always need to mention your Sharepoint version in your question. There are so many version in the sharepoint world.

Comment: I’m sorry it is share point 2016. I’ll check the logs and see what they say.

Comment: You may trigger a workflow first, get the error, then check the log with the error occur time. If there are still too many logs, search with keyword "workflow".

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the sharepoint content db storage has enough space.

Check content database report; right click database >> Reports >> Standard Reports >> Disk Usage by top tables.